# javascript function not getting called on submit

Tags: javascript, html

I have written the simple html javascript code for validation of username and password , but the function authorize() is not getting called when the form is submitted. Can any one help me find out the mistake in my code. I know same question exists and I did followed them but I wasn't able to find my mistake. Thank You.
Below is my code

```
<script type="type/javascript" >

    var users = {{"Username":"Sunny","Password":"Panzer"},{"Username":"Anjali","Password":"406460"}};

     function authorize()
    {
        var username= document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

        for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++)
        {
            if(users[i].Username==username && users[i].Password==password)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        alert("invalid username or password");
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

```
<form action="enter_details.html" onsubmit="return authorize()" >
    <center>Username  <input type="text" id="username"></center><br><br>
    <center>Password  <input type="text" id="password"></center><br><br>
    <center><input type="submit" id="login_button"  value="Log In"></center>    
</form>
```

Comment: try checking the developer console, you should see syntax error somewhere near the `var users = ...`

Comment: I assume this is just some kind of hobby or demo system? Verifying a username and password in browser code is completely insecure... anyone can just view the source code of the page with their built in browser tools and then see all the stored usernames and passwords. You should never ever implement this in a real user-facing system

Comment: Firstly , change your code <script type="type/javascript" > cause it's not right , the right way is :  <script type="text/javascript" >

Comment: @rapaelec amazing It worked. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose your JSON array in square (and not curly) brackets, like this:

```js
var users = [{
    "Username": "Sunny",
    "Password": "Panzer"
  },
  {
    "Username": "Anjali",
    "Password": "406460"
  }
];

function authorize() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].Username == username && users[i].Password == password) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  alert("invalid username or password");
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="enter_details.html" onsubmit="return authorize()">
  <center>Username <input type="text" id="username"></center><br><br>
  <center>Password <input type="text" id="password"></center><br><br>
  <center><input type="submit" id="login_button" value="Log In"></center>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

We have **two probleme here**

1- the users mus be an array of object like :

```js
var users = [{"Username":"Sunny","Password":"Panzer"},{"Username":"Anjali","Password":"406460"}];
```

2- when you insert your javascript code in html it is not : **type="type/javascript"** but **type="text/javascript"**

for resume your code must be like :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    
                var users = [{"Username":"Sunny","Password":"Panzer"},{"Username":"Anjali","Password":"406460"}];
            
                function authorize()
                {
                    var username= document.getElementById("username").value;
                    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
            
                    for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(users[i].Username==username && users[i].Password==password)
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
            
                    alert("invalid username or password");
                    return false;
                }
            
            </script>
```

I hope it's help you

Answer (score 0):

I believe your main is problem is that variable `users` should be an `array`. Your current syntax is not valid for the definition of variable `users`, and will thrown an error (you can inspect the console to see it). Check the next example with that fix.

```js
var users = [
  {"Username":"Sunny","Password":"Panzer"},
  {"Username":"Anjali","Password":"406460"}
];

function authorize()
{
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
    {
        if (users[i].Username == username && users[i].Password == password)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    alert("invalid username or password");
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return authorize()" >
    <center>Username  <input type="text" id="username"></center><br><br>
    <center>Password  <input type="text" id="password"></center><br><br>
    <center><input type="submit" id="login_button"  value="Log In"></center>    
</form>
```

Even more, you can simplify the `authorize()` function a litle if you use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
function authorize()
{
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    let res = users.some(user => user.Username == username && user.Password == password);

    if (!res)
        alert("invalid username or password");

    return res;
}
```

Comment: I did that but , bu its not validating when I am running it on my browser. And as your code in answer and my code is same after alterations , it is running when I run your code snipped below your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use event listeners

Add a id attribute to form

```
<form id="myForm" action="enter_details.html" onsubmit="return authorize()" >
    <center>Username  <input type="text" id="username"></center><br><br>
    <center>Password  <input type="text" id="password"></center><br><br>
    <center><input type="submit" id="login_button"  value="Log In"></center>    
</form>
```

And add event listener code in is

```
document.querySelector("#myForm")
.addEventListener("submit", function(eve) {
    eve.preventDefault();
    authorize();
}
```

If this didn't work try it on input button

```
document.querySelector("#login_button")
.addEventListener("click", function(eve) {
    eve.preventDefault();
    authorize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var users = [{"Username":"Sunny","Password":"Sunny"},{"Username":"Anjali","Password":"406460"}];

function authorize(){
        var username= document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

        for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++)
        {
            if(users[i].Username==username && users[i].Password==password)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        alert("invalid username or password");
        return false;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="authorize()" >
    <center>Username  <input type="text" id="username"></center><br><br>
    <center>Password  <input type="text" id="password"></center><br><br>
    <center><input type="submit" id="login_button"  value="Log In"></center>    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the callback function to submit the form, you need bind click on the 
submit button and use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the page jumps in the callback, which is the form default action

```
<form>
  <center>Username  <input type="text" id="username"></center><br><br>
  <center>Password  <input type="text" id="password"></center><br><br>
  <center><input type="submit" onclick="authorize(event)" id="login_button"  value="Log In"></center>
</form>






<script>

    var users = [{"Username":"Sunny","Password":"Panzer"},{"Username":"Anjali","Password":"406460"}];

     function authorize(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var username= document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

        for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++)
        {
            if(users[i].Username==username && users[i].Password==password)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        alert("invalid username or password");
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I test it on my computer, it works fine. And I can see the content of the alert